# Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it

Tags: xcode, app-store, testflight

I am facing the issue below after uploading app into TestFlight. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this? My project is in Swift.

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "QuiqRx Red". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Comment: You cannot submit from a beta version of Xcode. They are telling you to do it from a GM version, not from a beta.

Comment: I am having the same problem and I am using the GM version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not allow to submit apps from beta software, since there are possible bugs and flows in them which can limit the application's stability and usablility.

You should donwload the **final version** of Xcode from the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/hu/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) or from [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/download/) and build/submit your app through that.